# Calculating consecutive dates teradata

Tags: teradata

I am not an expert in Teradata or SQL so need some help in counting number of days a person has attended a customer

If a sales person has attended customer from 1 - 3 days consecutively this will be counted as 1 and if the person has attended 4 days then it will be counted as 2
I will add the example of data and result I want

**DATA:**

```
Sales Person    Date
John    1/03/2016
John    2/03/2016
John    3/03/2016
John    4/03/2016
John    5/03/2016
David   6/03/2016
David   7/03/2016
David   8/03/2016
David   9/03/2016
David   10/03/2016
David   11/03/2016
John    12/03/2016
John    13/03/2016
John    14/03/2016
John    15/03/2016
John    16/03/2016
John    17/03/2016
John    18/03/2016
John    19/03/2016
David   20/03/2016
Sue 21/03/2016
Sue 22/03/2016
Sue 23/03/2016
Lily    24/03/2016
Lily    25/03/2016
Lily    26/03/2016
Sue 27/03/2016
David   28/03/2016
John    29/03/2016
David   30/03/2016
John    31/03/2016
```

**RESULT WANTED:**

```
Sales Person    Groups
John    6
David   4
Sue 2
Lily    1
```

[Excel Format Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SatNB.jpg)

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since it doesn't belong there.

Comment: I don't understand your math.  Can you clearly explain how you arrive at 6 as a value for John?

Comment: Thanks Tim 
Here are groups for John

Comment: Group 1
John 1/03/2016
John 2/03/2016
John 3/03/2016

Group 2 
John 4/03/2016
John 5/03/2016

Group 3  
John 12/03/2016
John 13/03/2016
John 14/03/2016

Group 4 
John 15/03/2016
John 16/03/2016
John 17/03/2016
 
Group 5 
John 18/03/2016
John 19/03/2016

Group 6 
John 29/03/2016
John 31/03/2016

Comment: Tim you will be able to see in the picture I attached how I calculated the date groups

Comment: I still don't follow how John ends up with 6.  Update your question and show how you are tallying John's dates.  Given that no one else attempted an answer, I'm guessing that other also were confused about this.

Comment: HI TimThe question is every time a sales person visits the customer we have to pay him the criteria is if the sales person visits 1 day upto 3 days then he will be paid for one visit if these visits are within 3 days of the first visit. Example John Visited customer 01/03/17 , 02/03/17 and 03/03/17 so we will pay him only 1 payment for these days. but in the instance of 29/03/17 he visited customer and skipped 30/03/17 and visited again within 3 days. because his visit is within 3 days timeline we will pay him 1 payment . Thats how i have counted John's payments will be 6 payments.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem.

Here is a solution using ordered analytical functions and nested derived tables.
The final number of points per person is in person_points. I used analytical function sum() instead of grouping because I wanted to show the intermediate steps. The rule that days in a 3-day period that overlap a previous group should not be counted was a little tricky to implement.

```sql
create table t ( person varchar(30), dt date);
insert into t values('John','2016-03-01');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-02');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-03');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-04');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-05');
insert into t values('David','2016-03-06');
insert into t values('David','2016-03-07');
insert into t values('David','2016-03-08');
insert into t values('David','2016-03-09');
insert into t values('David','2016-03-10');
insert into t values('David','2016-03-11');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-12');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-13');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-14');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-15');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-16');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-17');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-18');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-19');
insert into t values('David','2016-03-20');
insert into t values('Sue','2016-03-21');
insert into t values('Sue','2016-03-22');
insert into t values('Sue','2016-03-23');
insert into t values('Lily','2016-03-24');
insert into t values('Lily','2016-03-25');
insert into t values('Lily','2016-03-26');
insert into t values('Sue','2016-03-27');
insert into t values('David','2016-03-28');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-29');
insert into t values('David','2016-03-30');
insert into t values('John','2016-03-31');

select t_points.*
   ,sum(points) over(partition by person) person_points
from
(
    select person, consecutive_group, min(dt) first_dt, max(dt) last_dt
       , last_dt - first_dt + 1 n_days
       ,floor((n_days + 2) / 3)*3 + first_dt - 1 end_of_3day_period
       ,max(end_of_3day_period) over(partition by person order by consecutive_group rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) prev_end_3day_dt
       ,case when prev_end_3day_dt >= first_dt then prev_end_3day_dt - first_dt + 1 else 0 end overlapped_days
       ,n_days - overlapped_days n_days_no_overlap
       , floor((n_days_no_overlap + 2)/3) points
    from
    (
        select person,dt
          ,sum(begin_new_consecutive) over(partition by person order by dt rows unbounded preceding) consecutive_group
        from
        (
            select person, dt
                ,max(dt) over(partition by person order by dt rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) prev_dt
                ,case when dt = prev_dt+1 then 0 else 1 end begin_new_consecutive
            from t  
        ) t_consecutive
    ) t_consecutive_group   
    group by 1,2
) t_points  
order by 1,2    ;
```

[image: Results]